# controller as syntax not working with angular 1.4.5 var vm = this template not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras

I had switched to controller as syntax with angular 1.5 -1.6 projects etc... 
The particular project I am need to add some functionality to a angular 1.4.5 project.

Usually I using angular routing etc..,  but this project is setup differently.

problem is in my template html,  i'm able to see

```
$scope.blah   //  {{ blah}}
```

but i am not understanding why or how to access `this`

**controller:**

```
icisNg.controller("hearingListing", ['$scope', '$rootScope',
    function ($scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.blah = 333;
        var vm = this;
        vm.whatever = 'controller as';
        $scope.atEnd = "endsdfgsdfgsdfg";
        console.log('scope', $scope.atEnd);
        console.log('vm', vm.whatever);

    }

]);
```

**Html template:**

```
<div fieldset-wrapper legend="Hearing" ng-controller="hearingListing">

    <div>test again</div>

    <div>{{blah}}</div>

    eewr
    <br />
    vm:{{vm.whatever}}
    <br />
    {{atEnd}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most expedient, based upon how your code is presented is to...

**Change**

```
ng-controller="hearingListing"
```

**To**

```
ng-controller="hearingListing as vm"
```

===

Also, please keep in mind that the variable `vm` in the controller *does not* refer to the same `vm` in your template. They are different and can be named anything.